# Filtering items using RemoveChild() and appendChild()

Tags: javascript, dom, filter, appendchild, removechild

I'm building a simple filter in Vanilla Javascript and CSS.

When the user click a category, the articles not related with the category have the class `.hide`. I also need to remove all these articles with the class `.hide` from the DOM, and append them again when the user click the category related to them.

The filter works fine adding and removing the class `.hide`. But the issue is, once the hidden articles have been removed, they don't appear again.

The JS:

```
const filterBox = document.querySelectorAll('.js-article');

document.querySelector('.js-filter-list').addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    if (event.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return false;
    let filterClass = event.target.dataset['filter'];

    filterBox.forEach(elem => {
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(elem);

        if (!elem.classList.contains(filterClass) && filterClass !== 'all') {
            elem.classList.add('hide');
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        }
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="c-filter__list js-filter-list">
    <button class="c-filter__list-item is-active js-filter-item" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="c-filter__list-item o-font-title js-filter-item" data-filter="cat-1">Cat 1</button>
    <button class="c-filter__list-item o-font-title js-filter-item" data-filter="cat-2">Cat 2</button>
    <button class="c-filter__list-item o-font-title js-filter-item" data-filter="cat-3">Cat 3</button>
    <button class="c-filter__list-item o-font-title js-filter-item" data-filter="cat-4">Cat 4</button>
</div>

<article class="js-article cat-1"></article>
<article class="js-article cat-2"></article>
<article class="js-article cat-2 cat-3"></article>
<article class="js-article cat-1" ></article>
<article class="js-article cat-4"></article>
<article class="js-article cat-3 cat-4"></article>
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to remove them rom the DOM? Isn't just hiding them with CSS a lot less work?

Comment: When you removeChlild it's gone, you can't add it again

Comment: @0stone0 I would like to remove them because I apply a CSS style with the pseudo selector nth:child(even) on all the articles. When the articles are hidden, they're still in the DOM so it breaks the CSS style.

Comment: Move them to a different (hidden) div

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks you have paired removeChild with appendChild - however, these are not actually opposites.   [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) will *move* elements that exist, not add new ones.  You'll need to `clone` your elements first, then you can happily remove them - or appendChild them back to where they came from

Comment: @freedomn-m Moving them into a hidden div is a great solution. However I've been looking for to achieve it and without success

Comment: Coulnd't you fix the css issue with a `not` selector?

Comment: Having a closer look, your code filters on class but the "class" to filter is in `data-filter` .  Can you update the question to include a snippet that has what you're currently working with, include css etc.  See [mcve]

Comment: TBH I prefer matching on data- , eg `elem.dataset['filter'] != filterClass`

Comment: Not much to add to what you already had:  https://jsfiddle.net/abt3s84o/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks a lot the snippet! You're right using data-filter, it's cleaner than parsing classes. However, using data-filter the filter doesn't work for articles having multiple categories.

Comment: @freedomn-m I found the way to get the data-filter attribute value for articles with multiple categories and showing up in the result. You can see the result here: [https://codepen.io/mathieupreaud/pen/JjxzGVW](https://codepen.io/mathieupreaud/pen/JjxzGVW). You can publish your answer in the discussion and I will validate it as it is the solution. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLElement and TextNode references can easily *live* as part of every JavaScript object without any connection to the DOM.

Thus, the OP should initially fill an array with the references of all available article nodes where they later can be (constantly) filtered from according to the selected filter-name.

The re-render process following a filter-change is as follows ...

- empty the root- or parent-node of all of its contained child-nodes.
- filter the initially filled array of every available article-node according to the currently selected filter-name.
- append every of the filtered array's node-reference to the article's root-/parent-node.

Other improvements are ...

- providing a common parent-node to the otherwise ungrouped article-nodes.
- use of [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) by adding just a single event-listener to the filter's root-node.
- separation of the filter's change-handling task and the pure (re-)rendering task.

```js
function emptyElementNode(elmNode) {
  const listOfNodes = [...elmNode.childNodes];

  let node;
  while (node = listOfNodes.pop()) {

    elmNode.removeChild(node);    
  }
  return elmNode;
}

function renderFilterRelatedArticles(filterName) {
  const articlesRoot =  emptyElementNode(
    document.querySelector('.article-overview')
  );
  const listOfFilteredNodes = (filterName === 'all')

    // ... either the initial array of every available article node.
    && listOfArticleNodes

    // ... or a filtered version of this array (by filter name).
    || listOfArticleNodes
        .filter(({ classList }) => classList.contains(filterName));

  listOfFilteredNodes
    .forEach(elmNode => articlesRoot.appendChild(elmNode));
}
function handleFilterChange({ target }) {
  // make use of event delegation.
  target = target.closest('[data-filter]');

  if (target !== null) {
    // get the filter name from `dataset.filter`
    const filterName = target.dataset.filter ?? null;

    if (filterName !== null && !target.classList.contains('selected')) {
      // handle the selected states of all the filter buttons.
      target
        .closest('.js-filter-list')
        .querySelectorAll('[data-filter]')
        .forEach(elm =>
          elm.classList.remove('selected')
        );
      target.classList.add('selected');

      // re-render the articles according to the passed filer name.
      renderFilterRelatedArticles(filterName);
    }
  }
}
const listOfArticleNodes = [];

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('.js-filter-list')
    .addEventListener('click', handleFilterChange);

  // initially fill an array with all the available article nodes.
  listOfArticleNodes
    .push(
      ...document.querySelectorAll('article.js-article')
    );
}
main();
```

```css
[data-filter].selected {
  scale: 1.1;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #333;
}
.article-overview {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-filter-list">
  <button type="button" data-filter="all">All</button>
  <button type="button" data-filter="cat-1">Cat 1</button>
  <button type="button" data-filter="cat-2">Cat 2</button>
  <button type="button" data-filter="cat-3">Cat 3</button>
  <button type="button" data-filter="cat-4">Cat 4</button>
</div>

<div class="article-overview">
  <article class="js-article cat-1">cat-1</article>
  <article class="js-article cat-2">cat-2</article>
  <article class="js-article cat-2 cat-3">cat-2 cat-3</article>
  <article class="js-article cat-1" >cat-1</article>
  <article class="js-article cat-4">cat-4</article>
  <article class="js-article cat-3 cat-4">cat-3 cat-4</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing all the explication and the snippet. Your approach on how the filter works looks great.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Btw right now the filter is based on an elemen's class-name. I would make the element-specific filer-name part of an tag's custom `data-*` attribute. The separation of presentational data and data which determines the filter logic is worth the sacrifice of the easy to implement class-name filter in favor of the more complex `dataset` based one.

Comment: Yes you're right. I also prefer using `data-*` than parsing the classes of an element.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to validate your answer. There are no questions left, thanks again for your help.